# How Chat app knows to pull from backend db server when new message is generated?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Here is a snippet of code from a chat app developed with Firebase and react native.

```
on = callback =>
        this.ref
          .limitToLast(20)
          .on('child_added', snapshot => callback(this.parse(snapshot)));
     }
```

Here whenever there is a new message is posted to Firebase, the callback in the app will sync with the firebase db and retrieve last 20 message.

I understand how push notification works and know in-app message is not push notification. But I didn't see a good technical article explaining how in app chat messages are synced between front end app and the backend database. I would think periodical pulling of backend database server from app would not be the most efficient way.

Here are more Firebase code associated with the code above:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'; // 4.8.1

class Fire {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
    this.observeAuth();
  }

  init = () =>
    firebase.initializeApp({
      ....
    });

  observeAuth = () =>
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged);

  onAuthStateChanged = user => {
    ...
  };

  get uid() {
    ...
  }

  get ref() {
    return firebase.database().ref('messages');
  }

  parse = snapshot => {
    ...
    return message;
  };

  on = callback =>
    this.ref
      .limitToLast(20)
      .on('child_added', snapshot => callback(this.parse(snapshot)));
 }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Are you just asking how the SDK works when it synchronizes contents of the database?  Is there something in particular that concerns you?

Comment: My question is how the  front app knows when to pull for update. Is there any API or SDK I can use if I want to implement my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach the first listener from the client to the database, the client opens a web socket connection to the server. It then sends the query/reference details to the server, which in turn loads the initial data (and send it back) and registers an internal listener on the server for changes.

From that moment on, if any change is made to the relevant data, the server scans the list of registrations, and sends updates to the affected clients. Those clients in turn raise the correct events, such as `child_added` and `child_removed`.

Comment: If I want to implement my own app listener and listener registration on backend db server, Any API I can use?

Comment: That depends on the technology your backend server uses. On a backend server you'd typically use either an [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) or the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start).

Comment: nodejs on backend and react native on front. websocket such as socket.io seems a way to go.